# Language versioning, security permissions and workflows in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

We have a multiple site, multiple language solution. We have a particular site (Site A) where we wish to have English as a "master" language, which is then translated and published in various other languages. We wish to prevent e.g. a French editor being able to edit and publish in any other language than French.

However, the French editor will have both English and French language read/write permissions, for their work on another part of the solution (Site B), so we can't use these to specify directly which permissions they have on Site A. We also use only removal of inheritence to limit role permissions, and never explicit denial, so permissions are cumulative.

Is it possible to create language specific workflows, with associated roles assigned to them, to prevent this editor from editing or publishing items in other languages?

Note: it would also be OK if this editor could publish in all languages, but only language versions that had been moved to the "publishable" state, and couldn't make a foreign language version publishable himself (so that if he did publish e.g. a German version it would only be a finished, publishable version, not a work in progress).

EDIT: To clarify, I don't mind my editor being able to publish all publishable versions of an item, as long as he can only edit in the one language he has ownership of for that site and cannot make other versions publishable.

If not, is there a standard/best practice solution to this problem?

Comment: This might be something you'd be interested in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690804/how-to-limit-sitecore-language-write-to-only-certain-parts-of-the-content-tree

It's not entirely the same situation, but I think the main points would go in this situation as well.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the last part: Only items which are in the final state of the workflow will be published anyway.

Comment: Please see my clarification, thanks.

Comment: Is the content editor/workflow approver the same person?

Comment: Yes, the only reason we want a workflow at all is to be able to mark versions as being in draft/finished. We'll probably end up by using a couple of extra languages that aren't used elswhere as a workaround for the language-write localisation problem, But I'll let the question stand as I think the Sitecore community could use some inventive solutions to this type of problem!

Comment: The problem is the fact the user has read/write to EN/FR but should only be able to publish FR. It sounds like a custom workflow step would just get in the way too, you don't really care about putting things into an "awaiting approval" step. Maybe look at overriding the publish dialog to hide the English language option? You'd have to store a list of users/roles that can publish a particular language somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

You can force Sitecore to publish only items to which a user has read/write access by changing the following settings in web.config:

```
Publishing.CheckSecurity = true
Publishing.RequireTargetDeleteRightWhenCheckingSecurity = false
```

[Use Default or Custom Access Rights to Control Whether Users Can Publish an Item](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/08/Use-a-Custom-Access-Right-to-Control-Whether-Users-Can-Publish-an-Item.aspx)

This does mean that you need to separate your roles and permissions out to be quite granular, i.e. you will need separate roles for Site 1 English Editor, Site 1 French Editor, Site 2 English Editor etc.

EDIT: Thanks for the clarification above and I can see where your problem lies. As I mentioned in the comments above, maybe you can hide/disable the language option on the Publish dialog. Just been taking a look at `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.Publish.PublishForm` and as expected there are a few private methods you would have to replicate, but you can add your own logic to `BuildLanguages()` to get what you need. Just duplicate `sitecore\shell\Applications\Dialogs\Publish\Publish.xml` to `sitecore\shell\Override` and change the codebeside to point to your custom logic.

I hate to add fields to system templates normally, but maybe add another field to `/sitecore/templates/System/Language` to specify which roles/user can publish that language. You can use the [Account Selector Field](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Account_Selector_Field.aspx) for this.

Comment: But my actual user will be a member of all three roles, so will have language read/write for both languages.

Comment: Interesting ideas, thanks. We would still need to handle the restriction on editing the wrong language somehow though. Our current proposal is to introduce new languages, not in use on other sites, and then use the standard language read/write settings, CheckSecurity and a basic workflow to control this. Like you, I don't want to make too many modifications to standard Sitecore templates and pipelines, prefer to build on standard functionality to keep the solution clean. The customisations required to handle both editing and publishing restrictions are deep, so we'd rather use the workaround.

Comment: Editing would not be an issue, you should be able to do that via roles for each language/site combination. The cleanest way would be as you have suggested, just make sure the locales match between the if you are using languages (but I presume you are duplicating an existing one)

Comment: No, language-write is a global property, it can't be localised to a part of the content tree without a customisation. That's why we're going to add extra languages. We'll probably just use languages with culture settings very close to US English, rather than create custom languages/cultures - it's a hack, but we don't want to have to install custom cultures on every dev machine and server.

Answer (score 0):

You can set security on workflow actions, thus preventing an action being performed by certain users. If that won't solve thing (because the same workflow is involved), you can always revert to implementing a workflow action yourself, this is easy.

Answer (score 0):

I have handled this in the past by creating multiple accounts for the user.  In your case, one for Site A in English and one for Site B in English and French.  It may not be ideal, but i don't think creating extra languages is either. Good luck!